# How tell the view an error has occured from controller? (Spring MVC)

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

How can I say trigger error/validation messages in the view from the controller in a better way? Currently, I do this by sending boolean attributes. For example, in creating a product, I have two possible errors. Invalid format of UPC of a product, or duplicate upc. I also have a validati

```
@RequestMapping("/createProduct")
public String createProduct(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
        @RequestParam(value = "upc") String upc, @RequestParam(value = "category") String categoryName,
        @RequestParam(value = "description") String description, @RequestParam(value = "price") BigDecimal price,
        @RequestParam(value = "stock") int stock){

    model.addAttribute("activeTab", 3);

    if(Validator.invalidUpcFormat(upc)){

        model.addAttribute("invalidFormat", true); //trigger for invalid format
        return "management";
    }

    Category category = productService.getCategory(categoryName);

    Product product = new Product(upc, category, name, description, price);
    InventoryProduct inventoryProduct = new InventoryProduct(product, stock);

    try {

        managerService.add(inventoryProduct);
        model.addAttribute("productCreated", true);
    } catch (DuplicateProductException e) {

        model.addAttribute("upc", upc);
        model.addAttribute("duplicateProduct", true); // trigger for duplicate product
    }



    return "management";
}
```

And here is my view:

```
    <div id="menu3"
            class="tab-pane fade <c:if test="${activeTab == 3}">in active</c:if>">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 2%;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"
                        style="padding-left: 15%; padding-right: 15%;">
                        <c:if test="${productCreated}">
                            <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                                    aria-label="close">&times;</a> <strong>Success!</strong>
                                Product has been created!
                            </div>
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="${duplicateProduct}">
                            <div class="alert alert-warning fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                                    aria-label="close">&times;</a> <strong>Oh no!</strong>
                                Product with the UPC ${upc} already exists!
                            </div>
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="${invalidFormat}">
                            <div class="alert alert-warning fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                                    aria-label="close">&times;</a> <strong>Oops!</strong>
                                Invalid UPC format!
                            </div>
                        </c:if>
                        <form
                            action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/manager/createProduct"
                            method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Name">Name </label> <input type="text" name="name"
                                    class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="UPC">UPC </label> <input type="number" name="upc"
                                    class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="category">Category</label> <select
                                        class="form-control" name="category" required>
                                        <option selected disabled value="">SELECT CATEGORY</option>
                                        <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="item">
                                            <option>${item.getName()}</option>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description">Description</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="price">Price </label> <input type="number"
                                    name="price" class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="stock">Stock </label> <input type="number"
                                    name="stock" class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add
                                product</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there a better of doing this other than sending boolean triggers?

Comment: Don't use request parameters. Use an object, bind the parameters to it, and validate the object. Everything else is handled by the framework.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "Use an object, bind the parameters to it, and validate the object". This is the way I've been using spring mvc. and im pretty new to spring and spring mvc

Comment: this one is a better approach rather than having boolean http://stackoverflow.com/a/22667775/410677

Comment: Spring uses binding, it will bind and convert parameters to a so called ModelAttribute (as explained in the reference guide). You can then write a validator to validate your fields (or use annotations) and have the errors automatically reported. You can even add your own errors (for instance like the duplication). Then you can use the errors object in your view to check if there are errors. If you use the Spring Form Tags all of that is handled for you already. Basically you are making things more complex by trying to work around things instead of utilizing the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Spring [`BindingResult`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html). This is typical filled with the result of Binding and Validation results. But you can also add errors by hand.

But first you need to refactor your code, so that you use an single command/form-backing object instead of all the `@Param` values

```
public class CreateProductCommand {
    private String name;
    private String upc;
    private String categoryName;
    .... //other fields
    public CreateProductCommand (){} //parameter less conturctor

    Getter+Setter
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/createProduct")
public ModelAndView createProduct(CreateProductCommand createProductCommand, BindingResult bindingResult)  //Binding result must be the parameter direct next to the object that should been validated!!!
{


    if (someustomValidationForUcpFail()) {
           bindingResult.rejectValue("upc", //the field name of the invalid field
                    "error.Message.Key",
                    "Default Error Message");
    }

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        model.add("createProductCommand", createProductCommand); 
        return new ModelAndView("createForm", model)
    } else {
        Product product = ...
        return new ModelAndView("showProduct", "product", product)
    }
}
```

jsp:

You need to use springs form and input tag:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:springForm="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
          version="2.0">
    ....
    <springForm:form action="<c:url value="/manager/createProduct">" method="POST" modelAttribute="createProductCommand">
        <springForm:input path="name"/> <form:errors path="name" />
        <springForm:input path="ucp"/> <form:errors path="ucp" />
        ....
    </springForm:form>
    ....
```